# AJAX and jQuery toggle/click states (resetting state)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm having a slight issue with a `.on` function and AJAX in relation to a mobile menu. The menu is in the header of an AJAX content driven site, so if an AJAX call is requested, the header and footer don't get recalled, but this is throwing out my mobile menu toggle as the 'state' is getting lost.

If I click an icon (hamburger icon) to open the menu, and click the same icon to close, on loading the site, it works fine, but as soon as I click on a link to navigate to another page it loses its state and I get some odd results (but in fairness, true results) where it opens and closes in one click etc.

I was using `slideToggle()` before but thought I would use a class, so I can remove and add the class to open the menu and then reset the class on the AJAX callback once the pageload is successful...

```
$('.menu-trigger').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('.non-active')) {
        $('.menu-trigger').addClass('active').removeClass('non-active');
        $('.menu').addClass('open');    
    } else {
        $('.menu-trigger').removeClass('active').addClass('non-active');                $('.menu').removeClass('open');
    }
});

$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    $('.menu-trigger').removeClass('active').addClass('non-active');
    $('.menu').removeClass('open');
});
```

Has anyone had any experience of this and perhaps how they got round it?

Comment: Maybe handler is called twice on each 'click', can you try: `$('.menu-trigger').on('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click', function(){...});`?

Answer (score 0):

try fade toggle

```
   $('.element').fadeToggle('fast');
```